# How to get the remainder of any equation

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am creating a function in which during the mint the fee will transfer to the contract not the whole amount but some percentage and the remainder of the equation I want to send that remainder to previous addresses.

```
//pseudocode
uint public fee=10;
function getRemainder()public {
uint count = fee*90/100; //(fee*90)/100; which equation is right
//how can I get the remainder of the uint count, above the line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uint public fee=10;

function getRemainder()public view returns(uint) {
    uint count = fee*90/100;
    uint remainder = fee - count;
    return remainder;   
}
```